# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate') - React Native while navigation based on functions approach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

Whenever i am trying navigate i m getting the Exception.
I had added all library to react stack navigator and also when i searching for the solution two approach are there one is function and another one is class based.

**App.js -My main App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button,Image,Alert} from 'react-native';
import Navigator from './routes/routes1';
export default function App() {

  return (

    /*Header*/

      <Navigator />

  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  homebutton:{
    width:300,
  },
});
```

Routes.js

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import LoginScreen from '../components/loginscreen';
import ResetHomeScreen from '../components/validateuser';

const screens = {

     Home: {
        screen: LoginScreen
      },
      About: {
        screen: ResetHomeScreen
      },
      initialRouteName: {
        screen: 'Home'
      }

}

const loginstack= createStackNavigator(screens);

export default createAppContainer(loginstack);
```

LoginScreen.js -Screen 1 for the navigation

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button,Image,Alert} from 'react-native';

export default function LoginScreen(){

    return(

        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
          <Button
          title="Go to About"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
/>
      </View>
    );
}
```

Validateuser.js  -Screen 2 for the navigation

```
        import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button,Image,Alert} from 'react-native';

    export default function ValidateUser(){

        return(

            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>About Screen</Text>
          </View>
        );

}
```

Kindly help me out on this and also please suggest me which approach is best class based or function based.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a name for all screens ?

Comment: Wich Version of React Navigation are you using? Where does the error come from ? is it for example after you press the button to go to home?

Comment: Ya correct after i had pressed that button "Go to About"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Functional Components you can not use **this**.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}

So instead of that use it like this:

```
export default function LoginScreen(props){

return(

    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
      title="Go to About"
      onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
      />
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot it is working now after i had removed that 'this'. And also can you please tell me which is better for a app development (Function or class) ??

Answer (score 0):

You can also use react hook functions to access navigation object in functional components.

```
import { useNavigation } = '@react-navigation/native';
const navigation = useNavigation();
```